# Error dev/kvm not found on windows

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have a problem in android studio AVD Manager

- I checked VT-x enabled in bios
- I Uninstalled android studio twice and installed it not useful
  [this image shows the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNVcW.png) 
  every thing i tried not help .. any idea ?

Comment: are you sure you've Intel virtualization technology enabled from bios ?

Comment: yes .. i was using it normally . just next day that happened .. until now i cannot find any solution

Comment: @HassanAlzubairHassan Could you please tell us how did you fix it.Even i'm facing the same issue.